# Retrieve output from HP Switch using Net::SSH2 Perl Module

Tags: windows, perl, ssh

[image]I am trying to connect to HP Switch via SSH using Net::SSH2 Perl module (Windows OS). The script is able to connect and authenticate to the device, but the output is not getting retrieved. I am getting blank output.

I have tried with Net::SSH2 shell and exec both, but no luck till now.
Also tried with Net::SSH::Any, still no result.

Hp Switch Model : HP 5900 - 7.1.045

**Code**

```
use strict;
use Net::SSH2;

my $ssh = Net::SSH2->new();

$ssh->connect('xx.xx.xx.xx');

$ssh->auth(username => 'xxxxx', password => 'xxxxxx');

my  $channel = $ssh->channel() or die 'Error creating channel';

$channel->blocking(0);

$channel->shell();

print $channel "display supervlan\n";       

sleep(5);      

 while(<$channel>)
   {
      print $_;
   }

$channel->close(); 

$ssh->disconnect();
```

Can somebody please help.

Comment: Your `or do { print }` is not exiting. You should be using `die` there, or also `exit` if you want your output to go to STDOUT.

Comment: @simbabque : Added "die" as per the updated code above, but still the output is null. Could you please help.

Comment: I've read the documentation, but I've never used Net:SSH2. And I don't have anything handy that I could ssh into, so I cannot help. Just pointed out an unrelated bug.

Comment: @simbabque : thanks a lot. Could you please let me know if you know somebody who can help in this forum.

Comment: You cannot ask specific people for help here. Stack Overflow is not a forum. Give it a few hours and someone will help. We're currently in the morning hours of Central Europe, so the regulars from the UK should be around. The Germans have a bank holiday today, so they might not be today. In any case, patience is important. If you need a solution right away, this is the wrong place. We're all volunteers here.

Comment: `print $channel "display supervlan\n";` Wild guess, but try sending a `\r` here instead of `\n`. The enter key actually sends a CR rather than a line feed.

Answer (score 1):

[Net::SSH::Any](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Any) can use any of available backend ssh modules (under windows uses Net::SSH2 if available)

```
use Net::SSH::Any;

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Any->new(
    "127.0.0.1",
    port => "22",
    user => "xx",
    password => "xx",
    strict_host_key_checking =>0
);
$ssh->error and die $ssh->error;

my ($out, $err) = $ssh->capture2("ls -l /");
print $out;
```

Comment: I tried the above code, but still getting blank output.

Comment: I didnt understand. Could you please elaborate.

Comment: `$ssh->error and die $ssh->error;` will output error message.

Comment: `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper $ssh;` will show more info.

Comment: script --> 
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

use Net::SSH::Any;

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Any->new(
     "10.31.142.104",
     port => "22",
     user => "hpoouserseu",
     password => "TR*ve##3R",
     strict_host_key_checking =>0
 );

$ssh->error and die $ssh->error;

print Dumper $ssh;

print "\nhello\n";

my ($out, $err) = $ssh->capture2("show version\r");

print $out;

Comment: I have attached the script output as well. Please check